# BackboneJS - Add class to tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I have a submenu with 3 anchortabs, which after clicking, the tabs become the additional class `activeSubLink`- to indicate which tab is active, showing a relevant collection. Now by default, when i render the view which contains the submenu, I want the first anchor to have the class mentioned before, showing the relevant collection. So far so good. When I hit the 3rd anchor it becomes the `activeSubLink`-class and shows the relevant collection. So far so good. Now, when I switch to a different page/view and return to my page/view again with the submenu, it still shows the collection from the tab I selected before switching to different page, but the `activeSubLink`-class is now set to default again, which means that first anchor/tab has the active-class, but showing the, in this case, wrong collection...

How do I solve this?

My HTML template looks like this (using HandlebarsJS)

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="sub1" class="sub1 activeSubLink" href="#">Subpage1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="sub2" class="sub2" href="#">Subpage2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="sub3" class="sub3" href="#">Subpage3</a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

and my View looks like this:

```
var SubMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    events: {
        'click .sub1': 'subpage1',
        'click .sub2': 'subpage2',
        'click .sub3': 'subpage',
    },

    subpage1: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.sub2, .sub3').removeClass('activeSubLink');
        $('.sub1').addClass('activeSubLink');
        $("#subpage2Div, #subpage3Div").removeClass('activetab');
        $("#subpage1Div").addClass('activetab');
    },

    subpage2: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.sub1, .sub3').removeClass('activeSubLink');
        $('.sub2').addClass('activeSubLink');
        $("#subpage1Div, #subpage3Div").removeClass('activetab');
        $("#subpage2Div").addClass('activetab');
    },

    subpage3: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.sub2, .sub1').removeClass('activeSubLink');
        $('.sub3').addClass('activeSubLink');
        $("#subpage1Div, #subpage2Div").removeClass('activetab');
        $("#subpage3Div").addClass('activetab');
    },              

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }

});

return SubMenuView;
```

I kind of get what the problem is but dont know how to solve it...

Comment: You can start with correct syntax for `<a id="sub1" class="sub1 activeSubLink" href="#">Subpage1</a>` ; missed a `>` .

Comment: @RoyMJ Yeah, just saw it, my mistake :-)... I mistyped here

Answer (score 0):

To reset the view, use the logic you already have and simply click on the first tab inside the `render` method.

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    this.$('.sub1').click();   // Click on the first tab
    return this;
}
```

You will need to make sure that `render` is being called when you switch back to the page/view.

Comment: Good approach, thats almost what I wanted.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I probably need a few more details, but generally you'd do something like this:

- store which tab is active in the model
- on `render`, load which tab is active and set the corresponding tab's class

You'd probably want to refactor some of the code you have to more generically set tabs.  For example, instead of a click event on `.sub1` `.sub2` `.sub3`, just add a class `sub` to all of the tabs and make a click event on `.sub`

Comment: Do you maybe have some kind of example to your suggestions?

Comment: sorry, no examples, give the backbone docs a read though.  It sounds like the way models work would be worth browsing.